# javascript - convert a date to local timezone

Tags: javascript

the below function should return a date and time that is in the local time zone. so if it is run at GMT, it should return 12 PM, at EST it should return 8 AM, etc

```
const today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + ((dayIndex - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7) + 1);
today.setHours(12, 0, 0);
var offset = today.getTimezoneOffset();
today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() - offset);
return today;
```

however what actually happens is the above code returns 7:00 AM at GMT and 9:00 PM previous day at EST. what is the mistake here?

Comment: The date created by new Date() is already in the local timezone. What is the setMinutes bit trying to do?

Comment: @rayhatfield I just want it to display the local equivalent of 12 PM GMT. if I don't apply that offset the return date is 1:30 AM EST.

Comment: In other, simpler words, you want to display the local equivalent of 12pm GMT/UTC of today?

Comment: @deceze if I run that code today in GMT it should return 9/7/2020, 12:00 PM and at EST it should return 9/7/2020, 8:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setUTC*` methods of `Date`:

```js
const now = new Date();
now.setUTCHours(12, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(now.toISOString());
console.log(now.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: I changed by time zone to America/New York and the second output is 7 AM. shouldn't it be 8 AM?

Answer (score 0):

Use the setUTCHours() method on the Date prototype:

```
const today = new Date();
today.setUTCHours(12, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(today.toString());
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) is the API for your reference

Comment: that kind of works but I changed the timezone to EST and I get 7 AM. shouldn't it be 8 AM?

Comment: @hitodo9051 EST is always -05:00. Many places that observe EST in winter observe **EDT** in summer, which is -04:00. So, if you're asking for the time in America/New York, it's 8am (EDT). If you're asking for EST, it's 7am.